# On WindowsMobile, how can i tell what other processes are reserving shared memory space?

Tags: windows-mobile, memory-management

On WindowMobile 6.1, I am using VirtualAlloc to reserve 2MB chunks, which will return me an address from the large shared memory area so allocations do not count against my per process virtual space.

(doc here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908768.aspx)

However, on some devices i notice that I am not able to reserve memory after a certain point.  VirtualAlloc will return NULL (getlasterror() says out of memory).  The only explanation for this that I see is that another process has already reserved a bunch of memory and my process is therefore unable to.

Any idea where I can find a tool to show me the shared mem region of a WM device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualAlloc(MSDN): This function reserves or commits a region of pages in the **virtual address space of the calling process**, so ...

[This tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/VirtualMemory.aspx) may be of help.

For data sharing use the [File Mapping Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms923218.aspx).

Comment: I've used that before. Doesnt it only show per process virtual addr space?  I'm interested in the shared virtual address space.